# Html input gets moved into label

Tags: html

I have this code, which is a simple form with a text input, a checkbox and a submit button.

```html
<form method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='email' id='email'></input>
  <label class='container'>Foo bar
      <input type='checkbox' name='newsletter' id='newsletter'>
      <span class='checkmark'></span>
     </label>
  <input type='submit' name='submitMail' id='submitMail' value='OK'>
</form>
```

But when it gets interpreted, it get like this (the second input is moved into the label):

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email'></input>
    <label class='container'>Foo bar
        <input type='checkbox' name='newsletter' id='newsletter'>
        <span class='checkmark'></span>
        <input type='submit' name='submitMail' id='submitMail' value='OK'>
    </label>
</form>
```

How come? And how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**: simple typo error. "Foo bar" zone contained generated text with an unclosed `<p>` and I guess the browser was simply trying to make sense out of this.

Comment: What do you mean, when it gets "interpreted"? and why did "Foo bar" change into "Blah" ?

Comment: Which browser are you using? In Chrome, the code sample you've provided renders exactly as it's written.

Comment: I can not replicate the problem, are you using any tool?

Comment: @ChrisCousins lol I'll edit that

Comment: @Tyler Roper Chrome 68

Comment: When I run the code and inspect it, in chrome, it looks perfectly fine?

Comment: `<input>` is a **void element**. It *cannot* have closing tags. Per the [w3c documentation:](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/syntax.html#void-elements) *"Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements."* Perhaps correcting this mistake will resolve your issues.

Comment: Alright, I noticed something. "Foo bar" is actually a generated code and contains a `<p>` (and no `</p>`) so I guess Chrome was only trying to make sense out of this.

Comment: The only time a browser will shift elements around like this is when something is syntactically incorrect, like an unclosed tag. I'd say your `<p>` is very likely the source of the issue :)

Comment: Thank you for your insights :) It was this indeed!

Comment: Glad to have helped. In this case, I'm going to vote to close the question as *"cannot be replicated/simple typographical error"* - this seems to satisfy both parts of that :)

Comment: Totally fine with this! Have a good day!